# Как отправить личное сообщение Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-api, facebook-graph-api, facebooksdk

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли как-то реализовать массовую отправку личных сообщений друзьям в Facebook через свой сайт?

То есть:
 1. Регистрируется на моём сайте
 2. Авторизируется через fb с нужными для отправки сообщений правами
 3. Получаем список друзей авторизированного пользователя
 4. Он выбирает кому отправить сообщение (одно для всех)
 5. Составляет сообщение
 6. Нажимает "отправить"
 7. Всё. Сообщение ушло нужным пользователям

Есть какие-то варианты реализации? Может уже есть нечто готовое на Laravel?

Answer (score 2):

В общем никак..

Вот этот вариант лучшее решение: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

С помощью Facebook SDK для JavaScript можно загрузить один и тот же URL-адрес диалога отправки:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'send',
  link: 'http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2015/04/15/travel/europe-favorite-streets.html',
});
```

Перенаправление на URL-адрес

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?
  app_id=123456789
  &amp;link=http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2015/04/15/travel/europe-favorite-streets.html
  &amp;redirect_uri=https://www.domain.com/
```